# JSF datatable: adding and removing rows clear rows values

Tags: jsf, datatable, addition, immediate-attribute

I have a h:datatable showing a list of rows, and the fields of each row are input fields.

I render an "Add Row" button before the table, and a "Remove Row" button on each row of the table.

The baking bean is viewScoped, and the buttons add/remove elements from the java list in the backing bean, and then return to the same view.

I set the immediate attribute to "true" in the buttons in order to not validate the input fields when I add or remove a row.

Everything works ok but one thing: the values of the input fileds are cleared. I thought that the view kept the values beacuse the bean is viewScoped.

How can I achieve adding/removing rows without triggering validations and keeping the values that were already typed by the user in the form?

My view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Añadir Fila" immediate="true" action="#{tablaController.addRowAction}" />
    <h:dataTable value="#{tablaController.lista}" var="fila" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <f:facet name="header">TABLA</f:facet>
        <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="NOMBRE" /></f:facet>
             <h:inputText id="nom" value="#{fila.nombre}" />
             <h:message for="nom" class="msjError" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
            <h:commandButton value="Quitar Fila" immediate="true" action="#{tablaController.removeRowAction(fila)}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="tablaController")
@ViewScoped
public class TablaController {

private List<Fila> lista;
...
public TablaController() { }
...
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.lista = new ArrayList<Fila>();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        Fila fila = new Fila();
        fila.setNombre("");
        this.lista.add(i,fila);
    }
}
...
public String addRowAction () {
    Fila fila = new Fila();
    fila.setNombre("");
    this.lista.add(fila);
    return "";
}

public String removeRowAction (Fila f) {
    boolean exito = this.lista.remove(f);
    return "";
}
...
}
```

**UPDATE --> MY SOLUTION:**

I write here my solution if someone is interested.

The problem is that I use immediate="true" to skip validations, but this makes to skip the update_model_values too, so that the values entered by the user in the form are lost after clicking the add/remove buttons and re-redenring the page.

As I use "JSR-303 bean validation", my solution was to skip validations using the f:validateBean to enable/disable them. Depending on the button I click, if I want the validations to execute, I enable the bean validation (for example in a "submit" button), and if I want to skip them, I disable bean validation (like in the add/remove row buttons). But anyway the update_model_values always executes, so the values are not lost.

Here's the view:

```
<h:form>
    <f:validateBean disabled="#{!empty param['disableValidation']}">
        <h:commandButton value="Añadir Fila" action="#{tablaController.addRowAction}">
            <f:param name="disableValidation" value="true" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:dataTable value="#{tablaController.lista}" var="fila" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <f:facet name="header">TABLA</f:facet>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="NOMBRE" /></f:facet>
                <h:inputText id="nom" value="#{fila.nombre}" />
                <h:message for="nom" class="msjError" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <h:commandButton value="Quitar Fila" action="#{tablaController.removeRowAction(fila)}">
                    <f:param name="disableValidation" value="true" />
               </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{tablaController.saveData}" />
    </f:validateBean>
</h:form>
```

The backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="tablaController")
@ViewScoped
public class TablaController {

private List<Fila> lista;
...
public TablaController() { }
...
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.lista = new ArrayList<Fila>();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        Fila fila = new Fila();
        fila.setNombre("fila "+i);
        this.lista.add(i,fila);
    }
}
...
public String addRowAction () {
    Fila fila = new Fila();
    fila.setNombre("");
    this.lista.add(fila);
    return "";
}

public String removeRowAction (Fila f) {
    this.lista.remove(f);
    return "";
}
...
public String saveData () {
    ...
    //processes the valid data
    //for example, calls to a service method to store them in a database
    ...
    return "";
}
...
}
```

Comment: hi i have the same problem, good solution.
but have you an idea how to disable built-in validators, like "required=true" ?

Comment: You can put required="#{empty param['disableValidation']}". This way the field will be required or not depending on the button you click. You pass the "disableValidation" param if you want to disable the required atribute.

Comment: @choquero70 You should post your answer separately. Don't just add it to the question. That way, it will be easier for SO users to parse and understand it.

Answer (score 2):

> *I set the immediate attribute to "true" in the buttons in order to not validate the input fields when I add or remove a row.*

`immediate="true"` is the wrong tool for the job. It should be used to **prioritize** validation, not to **enable/disable** validation. The difference is rather huge as you encountered yourself.

You want to trigger validation conditionally. In case of e.g. `required="true"` that'd be as easy as

```
<h:inputText ... required="#{saveButtonPressed}" />
```

where `#{saveButtonPressed}` evaluates `true` when the save button is pressed. E.g. when its client ID is present in request parameter map.

In case of JSR 303 bean validation, that'd be a matter of

```
<f:validateBean disabled="#{not saveButtonPressed}">
    <h:inputText ... />
</f:validateBean>
```

or with [OmniFaces `<o:validateBean>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean) which allows controlling that on a per-command basis.

```
<h:commandButton id="add" ...>
    <o:validateBean disabled="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. In short, you can NOT use immediate for action that update data table(UIData) or facelet repeat. Short explanation:submitted values are not kept for re-display if inputs in UIData do not go through validation. Long explanation can be found here: [long explanation](http://blog.flexdms.com/2013/07/immediate-action-for-data-under-uidata.html) and [a related bug in Mojarra](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2490)