# Add a new row to a p:datatable then submit content

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to add a new row in a Primefaces datatable, then I would like to submit the content of this table and do some business logic. The datatable model is a collection that is maintained in a ViewScoped managed bean.

I'm using JSF 2.1 with Primefaces 3.3.

Short example:

```
    <h:form id="my-form">
        <p:dataTable value="#{testBean.list}" var="s" id="datatable">
            <p:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{s}"/>
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Add row" action="#{testBean.addRow()}" process="@form" update="@form" immediate="true" />
                <p:commandButton value="Do stuff" action="#{testBean.doSomeLogic()}" process="@form" update="@form"/>
            </f:facet>     
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

private List<String> list;

public TestBean() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
}

public void addRow(){
    list.add(new String());
}

public void doSomeLogic(){
    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

// getters and setters

}
```

What actually happens:

- the user clicks on "add row" button, a new row is added (I need immediate to be true so no validation is done, those fields are part of a bigger form).
- the user clicks on "do stuff", the collection has the right size (with new rows) but the user's input in not taken into account (neither modification to pre exiting rows, nor new values in freshly added rows).

What can I do to submit the new values too? I'm only beginning JSF and I'm not sure I'm already 100% getting it.

Thanks for your help.

Possible duplicates:

- [Add a row to h:dataTable via AJAX with request-scoped bean without losing the row data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635013/add-a-row-to-hdatatable-via-ajax-with-request-scoped-bean-without-losing-the-ro)
- [How to Dynamically add a row in a table in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278353/how-to-dynamically-add-a-row-in-a-table-in-jsf/2280157#2280157)
- [JSF datatable: adding and removing rows clear rows values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092513/jsf-datatable-adding-and-removing-rows-clear-rows-values)

**Edit:** problem is solved thanks to Jitesh, a working example can be found here: [JSF2, can I add JSF components dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/jsf2-can-i-add-jsf-components-dynamically?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is you are using immutable object in inputText. To understatnd this check out [BaluC's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690850/adding-inputtext-elements-dynamically-to-a-bound-datatable-empties-other-inputte)

According to it "As being an immutable object, the String doesn't have a setter method. The  will never be able to set the entered value."

Try to remove immediate attribute from the commandButton you will find that on insertion of each row the data will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I removed the immediate attribute and used a bean instead of a String and that did the trick.

Comment: BTW, your link is broken, right one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690850/adding-inputtext-elements-dynamically-to-a-bound-datatable-empties-other-inputte)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there are some validations elsewhere in the form that are failing.  When any of the submitted form values fail validation then none of the submitted values are applied to the managed bean unless `immediate` is used.  This is why it seems that you are able to add a new row but not with the `doStuff` method.  You did not add `immediate` to `doStuff`.

But stating that there are a few things you could do much more cleanly and efficiently.

First, the `action` attribute should really be used for navigation actions. JSF expects that methods bound to an `action` have a return value that represents the navigation result.  For `void` methods it is better to use `actionListener`.  For more information on the difference between `action` and `actionListener` read here: [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Secondly, why not just set `process` and `update` to only the data table component and then you don't have to worry about other form validations?  Here is an example:

```
<h:form id="my-form">
    <p:dataTable value="#{testBean.list}" var="s" id="datatable">
        <p:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{s}"/>
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Add row" actionListener="#{testBean.addRow}"
               process=":my-form:datatable" update=":my-form:datatable" />
            <p:commandButton value="Do stuff" actionListener="#{testBean.doSomeLogic}"
               process=":my-form:datatable" update=":my-form:datatable" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: There are validations in my real code, but not in my example, which I use to try to resolve this problem. So `process="@form"` in this example == `process=":my-form"`. Basically your code does exactly the same as mine (I tested, same problem; click on "do stuff" and no new data is submitted). Thanks anyway for your advice about actionListener and action :)